# Lucene 4.0 on Linux - IndexWriter error: No locks available

Tags: lucene, indexing

When trying to index content with `Lucene` on `linux` I get the following error message:

> ```
> index/write.lock: java.io.IOException: No locks available  at 
> org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:84)  at
> org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:636)
> ```

My code works perfects on `Windows` and on `Mac OS`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Problem solved.
It seems that you can't open write.lock on the NSF. My solution which seems to work was to build the index on the local disk (/tmp).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solr over NFS problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599529/solr-over-nfs-problems)

Comment: @David good one. Don't ever store a lucene index on NFS :)

Answer (score 0):

Check locking services in file system where you are indexing

> ps aux | grep lockd

for more info :

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/No-locks-available-td2272029.html
https://serverfault.com/questions/61594/what-does-no-locks-available-mean

Comment: @David: Do u mean NFS?? did u try enabling locink service for NFS?