# How to use two solr instances in synch

Tags: apache, indexing, solr, devops

I am implementing apache-solr,i am getting few exceptions.

1.We have two instances of solr. solr1 is for indexing data and solr2 is for searching data. data directory is nfs mounted so that data indexed by solr1 can be read by solr2 for searching purpose. but solr2 is not able to read that data.

2.Another issue: in one of the core data import is happening properly but searching is not giving any document.

3.I dont want to use solr cloud.

Comment: Why don't you index to one instance and replicate to another?

Comment: can you send me steps?

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Index+Replication

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at the latest SOLR documentation https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/

Take a look at SOLR cloud https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/solrcloud.html#solrcloud

This will allow you to distribute your searching, and indexing.  You will also get resiliency.

Answer (score 0):

Using Solr or Lucene [over NFS is *in general* not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599529/solr-over-nfs-problems).

You can either use SolrCloud (but since you specify you don't want to use SolrCloud..), [explicit replication keeping nodes in sync](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Index+Replication) for serving data data - and you can easily add more nodes for serving queries by scaling horizontally, or you can [use HDFS for distributing data](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr+on+HDFS) across nodes.

For question 2; ask a separate question and attach details about what the documents look like, what the schema for the field looks like and what the analysis page under the admin interface says about how the field is processed.